# Regex for all kind of number variations

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to parse some strings that contain numbers and I want to find a regex that will extract all kind of scenarios:

.2345 0.934 12.3 11.0

Tried something like:

```
((\-|\+)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

But it seems like cases with .number are not covered.

Comment: What would you want to ultimately do with this? Just check if a string is a number or not?

Comment: Please show us actual code you've written, not just the regex.  Show us what was found and what wasn't found but should have been.

Comment: @Mureinik. Does sound like an XY problem.

Comment: @AR7. That does not apply here. OP is clearly asking to parse floats, while the other question is clearly int-only

Comment: @MadPhysicist: And an XY problem is ...?

Comment: @cxw. Fair enough. I found a better dupe

Comment: @BillBell. It's when a user asks "How do I do X" when they are really faced with problem Y and are on the wrong track. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346663. Some of the links are interesting.

Comment: Thanks, @MadPhysicist. I'll have a read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your RegEx is correct, but you want to parse numbers which starts with `.` also, so you can add `\.` along with `\-|\+` as follow:
`((\-|\+)?(\.)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)`

Note: It will match `.1.1`

Comment: Wouldn't match `12.`

Comment: Would match `.34.44`

Comment: I think in '12.' it should match only 12 and ignore .(dot), that's what my RegEx is doing.